# How to send an email template written in Quill editor?

Tags: angular, quill

I'm developing an email template making tool, and for this, I'm using Quill editor and Angular framework.

I wonder how to send an email template.
I could make an email template using quill editor.
However, I guess gmail can't show my email template well. because its style is in the quill-class no inline-style.

If you have an idea please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The Quill guide has an [example](https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#class-vs-inline) for using inline-style:

```
var SizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);

// Initialize as you would normally
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: true
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

A [live example](https://quilljs.com/playground/#class-vs-inline-style) in Quill playground.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Align is also available? I saw size and font color change like that on quill editor website, but I couldn't find align also can be written inline-style.

Comment: Yes, you can use align as inline style or attribute: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/align.js

Answer (score 0):

I think in general it will be hard to use a WYSIWYG editor that is not entirely built for emails, as email HTML has a lot of random quirks that are not coded around in the general HTML case.